# Glusterfs denied mount

Tags: glusterfs

I'm using GlusterFS 3.3.2. Two servers, a brick on each one. The Volume is "ARCHIVE80"

I can mount the volume on Server2; if I touch a new file, it appears inside the brick on Server1.

However, if I try to mount the volume on Server1, I have an error:

```
Mount failed. Please check the log file for more details.
```

The log gives:

```
[2013-11-11 03:33:59.796431] I [rpc-clnt.c:1654:rpc_clnt_reconfig] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: changing port to 24011 (from 0)
[2013-11-11 03:33:59.796810] I [rpc-clnt.c:1654:rpc_clnt_reconfig] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-1: changing port to 24009 (from 0)
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794182] I [client-handshake.c:1614:select_server_supported_programs] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: Using Program GlusterFS 3.3.2, Num (1298437), Version (330)
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794387] W [client-handshake.c:1320:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: failed to set the volume (Permission denied)
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794407] W [client-handshake.c:1346:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: failed to get 'process-uuid' from reply dict
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794418] E [client-handshake.c:1352:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: SETVOLUME on remote-host failed: Authentication failed
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794426] I [client-handshake.c:1437:client_setvolume_cbk] 0-ARCHIVE80-client-0: sending AUTH_FAILED event
[2013-11-11 03:34:03.794443] E [fuse-bridge.c:4256:notify] 0-fuse: Server authenication failed. Shutting down.
```

How comes I can mount on one server and not on the other one???

Comment: Please see log on `/var/log/glusterfs/` for exact error on glusterfs client host.

Answer (score 2):

It may a permission problem. Could you try if it can be resolved by set auth.allow:

```
[root@test1 ~]#gluster volume set ARCHIVE80 auth.allow 'SERVER1IPADDRESS'
```

It works on my side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try that before posting. After a while I realized that the gluster has to be stopped/started for the settings to be applied. The only solution I came up with was to "allow" everything and used iptables for security...